# I am trying to create two score boards for a baseball code

Tags: java, arrays

I am a beginner at coding so please don't flame :) Recently I've been working on some baseball tracking scores. However, I don't know if I am doing right.

I've got the first part of the code how I wanted it to be, but not the second one.

This is my original working code (the output is posted below)

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Baseball8
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        Scanner fin = new Scanner(new FileReader("baseball.txt"));

        final int LIST_LENGTH = 20;

        int number = 0,
            hits, 
            walks,
            outs,
            players,
            index,
            teamSize = 0;

        System.out.println("This program tracks a baseball player's number "
                         + "and their\nnumber of walks, runs and outs for "
                         + "each game in a season.\n");
        Player[] team = new Player[20];

        for (index = 0; index < LIST_LENGTH; index++) {
            team[index] = new Player(); 
        }

        while (fin.hasNext())
        {
            number = fin.nextInt();
            hits = fin.nextInt();
            walks = fin.nextInt();
            outs = fin.nextInt();
            index = findNumber(team, index, teamSize);

            if (index == -1 ) {
                team[teamSize].getNumber();
                team[teamSize].setNumber(number);
                team[teamSize].getHits();
                team[teamSize].setHits(hits);
                team[teamSize].getWalks();
                team[teamSize].setWalks(walks);
                team[teamSize].getOuts();
                team[teamSize].setOuts(outs);
                teamSize++; 
            }

            else {
                team[index].setHits(hits + team[index].getHits());
                team[index].setWalks(walks + team[index].getWalks());
                team[index].setOuts(outs + team[index].getOuts()); 
            }
        }

        displayArray(team, teamSize);

        fin.close();
    }

    public static int findNumber(Player[] team, int index,int teamSize )
    {
        int Save = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < teamSize - 1; i++) {
            if (index == team[i].getNumber())
                Save = i;
        }
        return Save; 
    }

    public static void displayArray(Player [] team, int team_size)
    {

        System.out.println("\n\nPlayer\tHits\tWalks\tOuts\n" 
                         + "------\t----\t-----\t----\n");

        for (int i = 0; i < team_size; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(team[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

and logically I thought adding these lines of code will give me the different score board

```
Scanner fin2 = new Scanner(new FileReader("baseball2.txt"));

while (fin2.hasNext())
{
    number = fin2.nextInt();
    hits = fin2.nextInt();
    walks = fin2.nextInt();
    outs = fin2.nextInt();
    index = findNumber(team, index, teamSize);

    if (index == -1 ) {
        team[teamSize].getNumber();
        team[teamSize].setNumber(number);
        team[teamSize].getHits();
        team[teamSize].setHits(hits);
        team[teamSize].getWalks();
        team[teamSize].setWalks(walks);
        team[teamSize].getOuts();
        team[teamSize].setOuts(outs);
        teamSize++;
    }

    else {
        team[index].setHits(hits + team[index].getHits());
        team[index].setWalks(walks + team[index].getWalks());
        team[index].setOuts(outs + team[index].getOuts()); 
    }
}
```

I also tried changing the index number to `-2` that didn't work either

And this is how the original output looks like

```
This program tracks a baseball player's number and their
number of walks, runs and outs for each game in a season.



Player  Hits    Walks   Outs
------  ----    -----   ----

 1       2       2       2
19       0       5       1
 2       0       0       6
18       4       2       0
 4       1       2       3
12       2       2       2
 7       0       0       3
 8       1       4       1
10       2       2       2
 3       2       1       3
11       6       0       0
 2       0       5       1
19       0       0       6
17       4       2       0
 9       3       2       1
 4       2       1       3
 3       1       2       3
 7       0       0       3
```

This is how I want it to look like

```
This program tracks a baseball player's number and their
number of walks, runs and outs for each game in a season.


Player  Hits    Walks   Outs
------  ----    -----   ----
1   2   2   2
19  0   5   7
2   0   5   7
18  4   2   0
4   3   3   6
12  2   2   2
7   0   0   6
8   1   4   1
10  2   2   2
3   3   3   6
11  6   0   0
17  4   2   0
9   3   2   1
Player  Hits    Walks   Outs
------  ----    -----   ----
1   2   2   2
2   0   5   7
3   3   3   6
4   3   3   6
7   0   0   6
8   1   4   1
9   3   2   1
10  2   2   2
11  6   0   0
12  2   2   2
17  4   2   0
18  4   2   0
19  0   5   7
```

But this is what it outputs if I put these 2 lines of code

```
This program tracks a baseball player's number and their
number of walks, runs and outs for each game in a season.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 20 out of bounds for length 20
        at Baseball8.main(Baseball8.java:67)
```

Comment: Why would you write all the code again instead of putting it into a method then calling it on the second file?

Comment: You have a `Player` class. Next, you probably want a `Team` class that holds a list of `Player` objects. The `Team` class should have functions like: `bool loadFromFile(String path)`, and `void printTeam()`, etc. Also, the `Player` class should override `toString`.

Comment: @Nexevis He said he's still new to programming so he's probably still not thinking in code reuse very well yet.

Comment: Looking at you code though, I have to ask why do you have that check for `if(index == -1)` when it should never be that value? You set `index = 0;` and then the only changes you apply are to increment it so it should never be equal to -1.

Comment: And a recommendation I would make would be to change your code to not rely on regular arrays for something like this which can have a varying amount of Players. Instead of a regular array you should use a [ArrayList](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_arraylist.asp) which can grow and shrink as needed. Then you can use it's `.size()` function to figure out how big it is for other logic like printing.